# Pandas groupby overlapping list

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataframe like this

```
   data
0   1.5
1   1.3
2   1.3
3   1.8
4   1.3
5   1.8
6   1.5
```

And I have a list of lists like this:

```
indices = [[0, 3, 4], [0, 3], [2, 6, 4], [1, 3, 4, 5]]
```

I want to produce sums of each of the groups in my dataframe using the list of lists, so

```
group1 = df[0] + df[1] + df[2]
group2 = df[1] + df[2] + df[3]
group3 = df[2] + df[3] + df[4]
group4 = df[3] + df[4] + df[5]
```

so I am looking for something like `df.groupby(indices).sum`

I know this can be done iteratively using a for loop and applying the sum to each of the `df.iloc[sublist],` but I am looking for a faster way.

Comment: there is same lengths of nested lists?

Comment: Nope. can be of any length. no repeats though.

Comment: `{f"Group{i+1}": df.reindex(x).sum() for i, x in enumerate(indices)}` ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
a = [df.loc[x, 'data'].sum() for x in indices]
print (a)
[4.6, 3.3, 4.1, 6.2]
```

---

```
arr = df['data'].values
a = [arr[x].sum() for x in indices]
print (a)
[4.6, 3.3, 4.1, 6.2]
```

Solution with `groupby + sum` is possible, but not sure if better performance:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'd' : df['data'].values[np.concatenate(indices)], 
    'g' : np.arange(len(indices)).repeat([len(x) for x in indices])
})

print (df1)
      d  g
0   1.5  0
1   1.8  0
2   1.3  0
3   1.5  1
4   1.8  1
5   1.3  2
6   1.5  2
7   1.3  2
8   1.3  3
9   1.8  3
10  1.3  3
11  1.8  3
```

---

```
print(df1.groupby('g')['d'].sum())
g
0    4.6
1    3.3
2    4.1
3    6.2
Name: d, dtype: float64
```

Performance tested in small sample data - in real data should be different:

```
In [150]: %timeit [df.loc[x, 'data'].sum() for x in indices]
4.84 ms ± 80.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [151]: %%timeit
     ...: df['data'].values
     ...: [arr[x].sum() for x in indices]
     ...: 
     ...: 
20.9 µs ± 99.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [152]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({'d' : df['data'].values[np.concatenate(indices)],'g' : np.arange(len(indices)).repeat([len(x) for x in indices])}).groupby('g')['d'].sum()
1.46 ms ± 234 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

On real data

```
In [37]: %timeit [df.iloc[x, 0].sum() for x in indices]
158 ms ± 485 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [38]: arr = df['data'].values
    ...: %timeit \
    ...: [arr[x].sum() for x in indices]
5.99 ms ± 18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In[49]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({'d' : df['last'].values[np.concatenate(sample_indices['train'])],'g' : np.arange(len(sample_indices['train'])).repeat([len(x) for x in sample_indices['train']])}).groupby('g')['d'].sum()
   ...: 
5.97 ms ± 45.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

interesting.. both of the bottom answers are fast.

Comment: Haha, I tried doing the groupings as you mentioned, but the issue is that the lists do have overlaps so the g's get overwritten. I think the best way for now is just doing the list comprehension.

Comment: @Landmaster - Interesting, there is broadcasting, so for me working nice...

Comment: @Landmaster - it seems second solution should be fastest, added performance timings with sample data.

Comment: seems like it.. crazy that extracting the list of values first and then doing the apply works best..

Comment: @Landmaster - If possible, can you test in real data? What solution is fastest? I guess second, but maybe not.